# Best way to get List from Observable in Rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

I'm just exploring Rxjava in one of my android application, and got stuck at one place, honestly speaking I'm very new to this library so don't mind if my question frustrate someone;-)

So I'm trying to access the Room Database using RxJava where I'm returning the Observable List, once I get this Observable I'm trying to use map operator to get a list of ids & query again the database, which again returns me the Observable List but the map operator expects List as a return type. How can I tackle this please suggest?

**Below is the code snippet:**

```
  private void getAllPcbs() {
    isLoading.setValue(true);
    getCompositeDisposable().add(
            getRepositoryManager().loadAllPcbDetails()
                    .flatMap((Function<List<PcbDetails>, ObservableSource<?>>) pcbDetails -> {
                        List<Long> pcbList = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (PcbDetails details : pcbDetails)
                            pcbList.add(details.getPcbId());
                        return getRepositoryManager().loadAllPcbs(pcbList);
                    })
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(this::onSuccess, this::onError)
    );
}

private void onError(Throwable throwable) {
    isLoading.setValue(false);

}

private void onSuccess(Object o) {
    isLoading.setValue(false);
    pcbList.setValue((List<Pcb>) o);
}



public interface DbHelper {
    Observable<List<PcbDetails>> loadAllPcbDetails();
    Observable<List<Pcb>> loadAllPcbs(List<Long> pcbIdList);
}
```

Comment: use `flatMap` instead of `map`

Comment: @SanlokLee I have tried flatmap but its return type is  ObservableSource<?>  ,i need List<Pcb> as return type.

Comment: Use `flatMap` and return `getRepositoryManager().loadAllPcbs(pcbList)`. Then `this::onSuccess` will be called with `List<Pcb>` type.

Comment: @SanlokLee Getting OnSuccess method like this private void onSuccess(Object o) {}

Comment: I can cast it but getting Unchecked exception lint

Comment: Instead of using `Object o` in your `onSuccess`, assign a specific type that you are expecting from the Observable.

Comment: Getting error Object is not convertible to List<Pcb>

Comment: If possible, please update your question with what you currently have including onSuccess implementation, assuming this is the place where you are getting casting error.

Comment: @SanlokLee updated kindly check

Comment: If everything is as written here, it should work, although I would have optimized the lambda function. If you are getting any casting error, check the object type just before the casting to see what type it is. You can also try logging `o.getClass().getSimpleName()`

Answer (score 1):

Go like

```
        getRepositoryManager().loadAllPcbDetails()
            .flatMapIterable {
                    listPcbDetail-> listPcbDetail
                // listPcbDetail is ArrayList<PcbDetails>
                // Converts your list of ids into an Observable
                // which emits every item in the list           
            }
            .flatMap { pcbDetail ->
                // pcbDetail is PcbDetails
                getRepositoryManager().loadAllPcbs(pcbDetail.pcbIdList)
            }.subscribe { listPcb ->
                // listPcb is ArrayList<Pcb>
            }
```